# NSSelectorFromString and Selector Struct

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime, swift4.1.5

I have a Question what is the different between NSSelectorFromString and Selector
 if i create the selector Using Selector

```
 let bSelector = Selector("registerRemoteNotificationWithApplication:")
 let cSelector = Selector(stringLiteral: "registerRemoteNotificationWithApplication:")
```

i get a warning

> String literal is not a valid Objective-C selector

and when using  the NSSelectorFromString

```
 let aSelector = NSSelectorFromString("registerRemoteNotificationWithApplication:")
```

there is no warning

even if the function was declared with / without  @objc

```
  @objc func registerRemoteNotification(application:UIApplication) {


}
```

Comment: What's your question? You are just writing the fact how current Swift works. What do you want to ask?

Comment: the compiler is giving me a warning when using Swift Selector Struct  but it dose not when using Objective-c runtime NSSelectorFromString  ,  so is there any  deferent between them ,  should i ignore the warning  or just use the NSSelectorFromString

Comment: You should better include the question sentence into the text of your question post.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Swift 3, you should use `#selector()` for this. Given

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc func registerRemoteNotification(application:UIApplication) { }
}
```

you would use

```
let selector = #selector(Foo.registerRemoteNotification(application:))
```